# Are questions about Chrome OS on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The primary purpose of Chrome OS is to run applications that are off-topic on Super User (web apps, plus it can run Android apps, both off-topic).

The devices it runs on (Chromebooks), are designed to be used primarily while connected to the Internet, with most applications and data residing online.  Their hardware configuration is typically similar to an (off-topic) Android tablet with a keyboard.

Chrome OS is capable of running some lightweight installed apps (to the extent they fit in what is typically minimal storage capacity), and there are some Chromebooks that could be considered notebooks.  However, the design purpose is running off-topic apps, and the typical hardware configuration is similar to off-topic hardware.

The tag wiki summary doesn't mention anything about Chrome OS, itself, being off-topic.  For that matter, netbooks do not appear to be off-topic.  Virtually everything Android is off-topic (OS, applications, hardware), and it is not due to the existence of the Android SE site.  So I'm trying to clarify the boundaries of Chrome OS being on-topic.

- **Apps**

  Web apps and Android apps are off-topic.  What about the non-Android installed apps?  What about the incorporated browser (is it a completely standard Chrome implementation)?
- **Hardware**

  If notebooks, sub-notebooks, and netbooks are on-topic and Android tablets are not, where do at least low-end Chromebooks fall in terms of scope?
- **OS**

  Are questions about Chrome OS, itself (user interface, utilities, interfacing with other devices, system maintenance, etc.), on topic?

Comment: Where do you see Chrome OS being out of scope?

Comment: @random: By "where", do you mean location where I saw it or the reason why it would be?  I have not seen this mentioned anywhere, which is why I'm asking.  The reason why it would/could be would be that the OS doesn't exist in a vacuum.  If the platform it runs on is off-topic, and the applications you use it for are off-topic, it's hard to imagine why the OS would be on-topic, or what kind of question regarding it would be on-topic.

Comment: The thing is, you didn't explain why the platform is off-topic (in the question), so it was kind of difficult to follow.

Comment: @random : because unless linked to a PC J2ME WebOS or android questions are not ?

Answer (score 10):

> run only off-topic applications (web apps)

This is not true. One of applications I use most often on my Chromebook is [Caret](http://thomaswilburn.net/caret/), which is about as much of a web app as Notepad++. Disallowing questions about Caret, or other Chrome OS applications designed for off-line use, seems arbitrary.

Also, let's not forget Chrome itself: web browsers are on topic here and not on Web Apps. If [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)+[windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)+[os-x](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/os-x) are on topic, why would not be [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)+[chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os)?

Comment: Good point about the apps.  I updated the question.

Answer (score -9):

I think we should apply the same usual behavior of Super User.
Do not allow computing question as long they are not related to PC hardware even if there are no other place on SE.

So Delete questions when they don’t involve PC hardware. The same way we do for ᴊ2ᴍᴇ Webᴏs; ɪos; and android.

Comment: Not I’m interested, but you can support my proposal if you need to ask pure Chrome  OS questions.

Comment: What about x86-64 and IA-64? You are proposing that we don't support 64 bit architectures (eg Windows 64bit) ? And 16 bit architectures?

Comment: @DavidPostill : As long as it is off-topic on both Super User and Electronics Engineering but still on about Power User questions then it would be welcome [my proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89327/?referrer=g49glRRR4LzIPUbvEVTUUw2). So for example near every questions from android.SE would be welcome here.